# MySql : How do I generate a query to combine more then 2 tables?

Tags: mysql

I have to generate an SQL query to fetch more than 1 table data with and without matching values and display the results. I used Left Join. However, it is not displaying all the values.

[image: Table]

My result needs to get all the questions and their corresponding answers for all the products, And also suggest me, Is there any flaw in the database table design? Thanks for your help.

**SQL**

```
SELECT 
    product.product_name AS 'Product',
    question.question_id AS 'Id',
    question.question_name AS 'Question',
    answer.answer_value AS 'Answer'
FROM
    question
         LEFT JOIN
    answer ON question.question_id = answer.question_id
         LEFT JOIN
    assessment ON answer.assessment_id = assessment.assessment_id
         LEFT JOIN
    product ON product.product_id = assessment.product_id
ORDER BY question.question_id
```

**The above SQL generated only the questions which had answers not all the questions**

Comment: Can you share the query you are using?

Comment: Can you post the query you created?

Comment: If I tell you that there are two flaws somewhere within questions, product, and result, can you spot them?

Comment: Do i need to introduce product column in the answer table?

Comment: @y_r_k Is that the exact query you are using or a simplification? _(Your LEFT JOINs will be effectively INNER JOINs if you have a `WHERE` with any conditions (that are not `X IS NULL`) on answer, assessment, or product fields.)_ Also, could you include the actual results you are getting as well? (assuming the results in the image are your expected results)